# Using wp_enqueue_media() with switch_to_blog() issue

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, switch-to-blog

I'm using WordPress media upload through `wp_enqueue_media();` to upload media. It works perfect.

But,

- I'm using multisite.
- Media upload is available on all sub domains.
- If someone upload image from `sub-domain1`, `sub-domain-2` etc then it should be uploaded into `main domain` media library.

I have tried `switch_to_blog()` & `restore_current_blog()` but it not works. Check below snippets.

### Working Demo

#### 1) Shortcode - [my-media]

```
add_shortcode( 'my-media', 'my_media_frontend_shortcode' );
function my_media_frontend_shortcode( $args ) {
    return '<button id="my-media-upload" class="button button-primary">Upload</button>';
}
```

#### 2) Enqueue media.js

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_media_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_media_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-media',
        plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) . 'js/media.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
```

#### 3) js/media.js

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {

        $( '#my-media-upload' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

           var file_frame = wp.media({
                title: 'Media',
                button: {
                    text: 'Upload Media',
                },
                multiple: false
            });

            file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
                var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                console.log( attachment ); // Works
                console.log( attachment.url ); // Works
            });

            file_frame.open();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

### Trying to use switch_to_blog()

I have used `switch_to_blog()` & `restore_current_blog()` to use MAIN site to upload all media. But, It not works.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_media_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_media_enqueue_scripts() {

    // Switch to blog 1
    switch_to_blog( 1 );

    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-media',
        plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) . 'js/media.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

    // Restore to current blog.
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

After digging I found `ajax_query_attachments_args` is used in AJAX hook `wp_ajax_query_attachments`. I use it and it works.

But `break` the sub domain media library. It does not restore the domain.

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'my_site_switch_to_blog' );
function my_site_switch_to_blog( $args ) {

    // Switch to Blog 1.
    switch_to_blog( 1 );
    return $args;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this with Action/Filter?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I have now save the images on the main site.